# Issue : Exporting table from hadoop to mysql

Tags: hadoop

This is my sqoop script  for exporting table from hadoop to mysql:

```
export
## Database details
--connect
jdbc:mysql://mktgcituspoc1.cisco.com:3306/poc
--username
pocuser
--password
pocuser
## Table to export to
--table
mktg_site_pub
--export-dir
##/app/MarketingIT/warehouse/mktg_mbd.db/performance_tst
/app/dev/MarketingIt/warehouse/hddvmktg/mktg_mbd.db/mktg_site_pub
--input-fields-terminated-by
'|'
--input-null-string
'\\N'
--input-null-non-string
'\\N'
-m
```

I'm getting the following error after running the above sqoop script..

```
15/02/19 02:16:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201502172305_2648_m_000016_1, Status : FAILED on node hdnprd-c01-r01-05
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:680)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:346)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:282)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:271)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:140)
        at mktg_site_pub.__loadFromFields(mktg_site_pub.java:3622)
        at mktg_site_pub.parse(mktg_site_pub.java:3549)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
        ... 10 more
```

Can anyone please help to figure out whats the exact issue?

Comment: Did you check the log of the job (in Hue or _hadoop job -logs <job-id> <attempt-id>_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly likely that you have a date-related field in MySQL that you are trying to export a non-date value into.

Check which fields in the MySQL table have that type and then check that the corresponding values in your Hadoop data set can be converted to a Java `Date` using [`Date.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thanks!! The error was due to type mismatch of the fields :(